# 404 error when trying to list envelopes in react sample app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docusignapi

I am attempting to get the docusign react sample app up and running (https://github.com/docusign/eg-02-react-implicit-grant).

When I click "List envelopes" the app directs me to sign into my docusign account, then successfully redirects back to the react app. However I get the following errors and no listed envelopes:

[image]

[image]

What am I missing? I have added the following redirect URIs to my docusign account and updated the dsConfig.js in the project with the integration key for my app.

[image]

How can I get this sample project to list envelopes / send and sign them?

Comment: Your react app usually runs on port 3000, you are making a call to localhost:3000. Is your server in your react app?

Comment: What server are you referring to? I am not running anything other than the react app. I am doing implicit grant auth which forgoes needing to run Apache for a CORS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

the call to the userInfo API should be made to the DocuSign endpoint, not to your localhost.

It should be:

```
GET https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo
```

(see more information on this call - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints)

Comment: I believe this has to do with the redirect URI in my dsConfig.js. Presently it is set to "http://localhost:3000". Should it be something else?

Comment: the redirect URI is where your app continues after you get the token from DocuSign as part of the auth process. localhost is fine. I saw userinfo in the url that gave you the error so that's a different issue.